# how to validate log out only once in visual studio c# via access database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

Form

[image: Form]

Database

[image: Database]

I want to make an employee Check in and Out form the check in part is done perfectly. 
But for check out the update query allows to edit pre-entered values to change, I don't want already entered values to be able to change afterwards, and only enter Out_time to free cells.

Below is my code:

```
private void out_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update Daily_emp_track set Out_Time='" + time1.Text + "' where Emp_ID=" + id_txt.Text + " ";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("You are out");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Entered ID not valid ");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the entered value from being changed again and get Out_Time by system instead of inputting manually, you could refer to the following code：

```
private void out_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        string time1;
        if (time.Hour > 12)
        {
            time1 = time.Hour - 12 + ":" + time.Minute + " PM";
        }
        else
        {
            time1 = time.Hour + ":" + time.Minute + " AM";
        }
        try
        {
            string OutTime;
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT Out_Time FROM Daily_emp_track WHERE Emp_ID='" + id_txt.Text + "'";
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                OutTime = reader["Out_Time"].ToString();
                if (OutTime != "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Out Time has submitted");
                }
                else
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Daily_emp_track SET Out_Time='" + time1 + "' WHERE Emp_ID='" + id_txt.Text + "'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("You are out");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Entered ID not valid ");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```